# Set Entire Tenant to Only Owner Can Share in all SharePoint Online Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to set the default Access Request Setting to Off for the Entire Organization so that only the person who creates the site ( Site Owner ) can share documents, links, and files?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible to set only site owners can share as default in all sites. SharePoint online is not yet able to establish such permission policy.

You can make your suggestions in the [user voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/).